# Trigger an Azure Pipeline Build on push to a sub-module?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, yaml, build-pipeline

I'm working with a repository (`A`) that contains a different repo as a sub-module (`B`). The contents of repo `B` is used by the logic in `A`, and needs to be updated regularly.

I currently have an Azure build pipeline which is triggered whenever a push to `A` occurs. I've also made sure that the artifact created by the build contains data from `B`. This is defined in Yaml; in short:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master # <-- Trigger a build when the branch 'master' is pushed to!
```

I can see in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines#trigger-batch-branches-paths-tags) that it is possible to connect this trigger to different branches and / or paths in the same repository.

The problem is that as a sub-module, Repo `B` is really a completely separate repo, which is pushed to quite separately from `A`. This means that even though `B` is updated when `A` is pulled during the build pipeline, pushes to `B` do not automatically register as pushes to `A`, so the build is not triggered.

I would be great if I could do something similar to the following to make up for this...

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - my-other-repo-B # <-- Trigger a build when B is pushed to!
```

... but this does not seem to be possible, as far as I can tell.

My current best option seems to be to create a separate build for `B`, and then add an extra trigger in Azure DevOps which initiates the main build whenever that has run. That should in theory work, but I would really prefer to control both triggers for the build in the same place, if possible.

Are there any other good / clean ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **repository resource** to trigger a pipeline when push occurs on another repository.

1. If **`RepoA`** and **`RepoB`** are in the same project, you can set up like as below in the YAML file of your build pipeline.

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: subRepos  # The ID of the repository. You can customize it here.
    type: git
    name: RepoB  # The actual name of the repository.
    trigger:  # CI trigger
      batch: true
      branches:  # branch filter
        . . .
      paths:  # path filter
        . . .
      tags:  # tag filter
        . . .
```

2. If **`RepoB`** is in a different project (e.g. **`ProjB`**) within the same organization, you can set up like as below in the YAML file of your build pipeline.

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: subRepos
    type: git
    name: ProjB/RepoB
    trigger:
      batch: true
      branches:
        . . .
      paths:
        . . .
      tags:
        . . .
```

For more details, you can reference the following documents:

- [**Repository resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines)
- [**Multiple repositories**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers)